# Can I change difficulties after I start?

Tags: torchlight-2

I started on Normal. I always start on Normal.  Now that I have played some of the game and have the mechanics down, can I switch difficulties for my current character?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes, it is possible. You need to create a LAN game and then you can specify the difficulty there. A couple of important notes: if you tick "reroll world" it will generate a whole new world but I *think* quest progress is still saved.  Also, I've heard tell that even if you *don't* reroll the world that all the monsters in your LAN game will be respawned.  I haven't done this yet so I can't give you my experiences.

[Here is a forum thread](http://forums.runicgames.com/viewtopic.php?f=30&t=37867&p=338525&hilit=difficulty#p338525) at the official Torlight 2 forums explaining this.

Comment: Both good answers, gave you the check because you were first.

Answer (score 15):

There is currently no regular option to change single player difficulty for a specific character. However, you have two options for this:

1. Start a LAN game on your own. You can select any difficulty level when you host the game.
2. Use the game console (**note the last part about being flagged**):

   > If you enable and use the console, you can change difficulty with the
   >   command "setdifficulty #" where # is a number between 0 and 3, from
   >   easy to elite.
   >
   > To enable the console, open the settings.txt file located in My
   >   Documents/My Games/Runic Games/Torchlight 2/Save Then scroll down
   >   until you see CONSOLE: 0, and change the `0` to a `1`. To open the console
   >   ingame, press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>NUMPAD_0</kbd>.
   >
   > If you use the console, it flags your character as a console user.
   >   Other players online will be able to see a mark next to your portrait.
   >   If you don't care about this, go ahead, otherwise I'd stick to just
   >   remaking LAN games and changing the difficulty there.
   >   
   > [Source](http://forums.runicgames.com/viewtopic.php?f=30&t=35025)

Comment: you can open the Console window while in-game by pressing Insert.