# Can I join someone's normal mode game with my elite mode character?

Tags: torchlight-2

I have many characters in Torchlight 2 but they all are in elite mode. Can I join the game of another player who is playing on a different difficulty?

Alternatively, once started in elite mode I can change it to normal mode? Or is only when you start?

Comment: The answer will be one can join and even create games of all difficulties in Internet and LAN. Detailed answers are at https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/85874/can-i-change-difficulties-after-i-start?rq=1

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can I change difficulties after I start?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/85874/can-i-change-difficulties-after-i-start) (per previous comment)

Answer (score 0):

If you are talking about LAN game, yes it is possible: in this mode, you choose difficulty at the beginnning of the game: it's the game's host that choose it.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there are no difficulty restrictions.
You could even create an elite character then create a private room in easy and play the entire game if you wish so.

However, you cant play together if your character is currently in NG+ and the other player isn't (or vice versa).